# Lg Aristo 2 Fastboot flash recovery - FAILED (remote: 'unknown command')

Tags: twrp, lg

I've recently been trying to flash twrp on my Lg Aristo 2, when I ran the code to OEM Unlock a device it came out with the same "FAILED (remote: 'unknown command')".
I started my phone back up and it came to a set up screen, I set up my phone and it said it was OEM Unlocked. When I try to flash a custom recovery, or run any command with fastboot at the beginning  i get "FAILED (remote: 'unknown command')" and it doesn't work. Can someone please help?

Comment: `adb devices` and `fastboot devices` does show the phone serialno?

Answer (score 1):

Seems fastboot is broken or disabled since Oreo.
First you have to downgrade ROM to Nougat. You can flash *.KDZ files with LGUP or LG Flash Tool.

[image: LGUP]

Then it should work as usual:

- Make sure you have enabled
  System Settings > About Phone > Developer Options > Enable OEM unlock,
  and
  System Settings > About Phone > Developer Options > Enable USB debugging
- check adb is working

  ```
  adb devices
  ```
- check fastboot is working

  ```
  adb reboot bootloader
  fastboot devices
  ```

WARNING: Factory reset, all data lost!

- unlock the bootloader (one of these should work)

  ```
  fastboot oem unlock
  fastboot flashing unlock
  ```
- if unlocking was successful, you can test recovery without flashing

  ```
  fastboot boot <path>/recovery.img
  ```
- then reboot into bootloader and flash recovery

  ```
  adb reboot bootloader
  fastboot flash recovery <path>/recovery.img
  ```

Comment: if you fail on one of these steps, make sure you have installed latest drivers and platform tools https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip

Comment: fastboot flashing unlock comes out to:                                                                              (bootloader)                                                          Device already : unlocked!
OKAY [  0.003s]
Finished. Total time: 0.008s                                                                                     fastboot boot recovery.img comes out to:            Sending 'boot.img' (16954 KB)                      OKAY [  0.555s]
Booting                                            FAILED (remote: 'unknown command')
fastboot: error: Command failed

Comment: check path is quoted correctly for example `fastboot flash recovery "C:\Users\My Name\Downloads\twrp-recovery.img"` edit: ok then your recovery.img might be corrupt, try a different one

Comment: Did that got same error, also downloaded the recovery.img again

Comment: Downgrade your firmware to the LMX210MA https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3805141

Comment: Well I need TWRP to do that and the comment to flash TWRP fails, I also couldn’t find any app to root, and I cant use TWRP to root

Comment: use LGUP see page 2 XDA scroll down post #20

Comment: So, after an eternity of research, I was able to get LGUP to recognize my device. I flashed a stock KDZ file, and booted it into fast boot mode, I got the same FAILED (remote: ‘unknown comamnd’). I just need a KDZ file with the correct partition layout, would you be able to tell me which firmware update/downgrade will let me do this from the link you provided?

Comment: tecknight recommend 10K or earlier  
http://lg-firmwares.com/lg-lmx210ma-firmwares/#tab=firmwares  
`X210MA10c_00_MPCS_US_OP_1207.kdz` is oldest available on this site